# Custom Event Receiver - Copy To Folder

Tags: events, sharepoint-2010, event-handling

I am in the process of writing a custom event receiver. The basic flow is as follows:

1. Document is added to Library
2. Based on metadata of document, we check to see if a folder within another document    library exists.
3. If the folder does not exist, it is created.
4. The newly added document is copied to the folder residing in another document library.

I have got myself to the point, where I can copy newly added files, from one document library to another when they are added. However I cannot figure out how to copy to a specific directory (by name) within a document library. Any help would be greatly received.

Here is my code so far:

```
SPFile sourceFile = properties.ListItem.File;
SPFile destFile; // Copy file from source library to destination         
using (Stream stream = sourceFile.OpenBinaryStream())
{
    var destLib = (SPDocumentLibrary) properties.ListItem.Web.Lists[listName];
    destFile = destLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(sourceFile.Name, stream);
    stream.Close();
} 
// Update item properties         
SPListItem destItem = destFile.Item;
SPListItem sourceItem = sourceFile.Item;
// Copy meta data
destItem["Title"] = sourceItem["Title"];
//...        
//... destItem["FieldX"] = sourceItem["FieldX"];        
//...         
destItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

```
//Ensure folder here 

var destFolder = destLib.RootFolder.SubFolders["name"]; 

destFile = destFolder.Files.Add(sourceFile.Name, stream);
```